# python one line function definition

Tags: python

This must be simple, but as an only occasional python user, fighting some syntax.
This works:

```
def perms (xs):
    for x in itertools.permutations(xs): yield list(x)
```

But this won't parse:

```
def perms (xs): for x in itertools.permutations(xs): yield list(x)
```

Is there some restriction on the one-line function syntax?
The body definition (for...) can be either two or one line by itself, and the def: can be one or two lines with a simple body, but combining the two fails.
Is there a syntax rule that excludes this?

Comment: FTR on Python 3.3 `def perms (xs): yield from map(list,  itertools.permutations(xs))`

Comment: As an occasional Python user you should try and learn that in Python, layout matters. Readability counts much more than being able to write one-liners. If in doubt, make it look the way you would like to see it if you had to maintain it.

Comment: I know layout matters since the first version used it and works. Readability is subjective, and the single line style for something this simple is what I wanted, and also I wanted to understand the syntax issues better.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes, there are restrictions. No, you can't do that. Simply put, you can skip one line feed but not two.

See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html).

The reason for this is that it would allow you to do

```
if test1: if test2: print x
else:
    print y
```

Which is ambiguous.

Comment: Not to mention it just looks bad.

Comment: Thanks - just what I wanted, a reference to the proper rule in the spec.

Answer (score 60):

If you *must* have one line just make it a `lambda`:

```
perms = lambda xs: (list(x) for x in itertools.permutations(xs))
```

Quite often, when you have a short `for` loop for generating data you can replace it with either list comprehension or a generator expression for approximately the same legibility in slightly less space.

Comment: Thanks - great answer and very helpful - but since I can only check one as "the answer" and was looking for the syntax rule, I checked the one above.

Comment: @guthrie - no problems at all - this is definitely only a supplement to Lennart's excellent answer :-)

Comment: you could also use a one line named function as: `def perms(xs): return (list(x) for x in itertools.permutations(xs))`

Comment: pylint will complain on this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010167/e731-do-not-assign-a-lambda-expression-use-a-def

Answer (score 8):

In your case, I am not sure. But with some functions you can achive this by using semicolons.

```
>>> def hey(ho): print(ho); print(ho*2); return ho*3
...
>>> hey('you ')
you
you you
'you you you '
```

Comment: Works inside the interpreter, but seems to not working inside "python -c", unfortunately. For example: python -c 'def func(x): print(x); func(1)'

Comment: @AlexanderSamoylov I tried to execute your example and there were no issues. Looks like this was fixed.

Comment: @Amuoeba, did you really use "python -c"? For me it does not work and I tried python 2.x and 3.x. It returns 0, but it prints nothing. I am suspecting that it happens, because python cannot understand where the "def" implementation ends inside the one-line script 'def func(x): print(x); func(1)' and considers "func(1)" as a part of the function, but not as a call inside main program.

Comment: Hmmm yes true, I was to hasty. I was just looking for errors, it does not print anything  in my case as well. Possible, it seems like you can't call a function that was defined in the same line. I tried putting your example in a script with just this 
line and it doesn't work as well. but then i put this in a script

# [line 1] def func(x): print(["a" for c in range(x)]);print(1); return x; func(10);
# [line 2] a = func(10)
# [line 3] print(a)

And "a" gets the expected value assigned (10) and also all prints are executed. So this issue doesn't introduce any logical issues.

Answer (score 4):

def perms (xs):

for x in itertools.permutations(xs): yield list(x)

You can use `exec()` to help this problem

```
exec('def perms (xs):\n  for x in itertools.permutations(xs):\n   yield list(x)\n')
```

*beware to insert indented spacing or chr(9) after \n*

Example for if Python in one line

```
for i in range(10):
 if (i==1):
  print(i)

exec('for i in range(10)\n  if (i==1):\n   print(i)\n')
```

[This is My project on GitHub](https://github.com/supotmaild/BasicPy) to use exec to run Python program in interactive console mode

*note multiple line exec run only when end with '\n'

Comment: Though this is an interesting workaround, it is about as unpythonic as you can possibly ever get.

Comment: Looks more like something that javascript would do

Comment: does that mean you can `exec("<do something" \n exec('<do more things>')")`? because this could end up getting very messy, especially if you begin putting this inside a lambda

Comment: This is the only solution which works for "python -c"! 
Example: python -c 'import sys; exec("def func(x):\n    sys.stdout.write(\"x=%d\\n\" % x);\n"); func(1);'