# Storing code inside a dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary, lambda

I'm getting into Python, and though of writing my own script which allows me to check arguments provided when a program is run. An example below of what I'm trying to achieve:

`python file.py -v -h anotherfile.py`
or
`./file.py -v -h anotherfile.py`

In these two cases, the `-v` and `-h` arguments, print out the module version, and a basic help file. I already have the code to differentiate between arguments and files, except I want to create a generalised module on the matter.

The following code written in Java-

```
// Somewhere.
public static HashMap<String, Runnable> args = new HashMap<String, Runnable>();
public void addArgument(String argument, Runnable command) {
    if (argument.length() > 0) {
        if (args.get(argument) == null) {
            args.put(argument, command);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Cannot add argument: " + argument + " to HashMap as the mapping already exists.");
            // Recover.
        }
    }
}

// Somewhere else.
foo.addArgument("-v", () -> {System.out.println("version 1.0");});
foo.args.get("-v").run();
```

-will run the Lambda Expressions *(atleast that's what I read they were when researching the topic)* successfully. I have no idea how Lambda Expressions work however, and have only basic knowledge of using them.

**The point of this question, is how can I implement something like the Java example, in Python, storing any type of code inside of an array?**

The thing is with the Java example though, if I have `int i = 0;` defined in the class which executes `addArgument` and uses `i` somehow or rather, the class containing `addArgument` knows to use `i` from the one that invoked it. I'm worried that this may not be the same case for Python...

I want to be able to store them in dictionaries, or some other sort of key-based array, so I can store them in the following manner:

```
# Very rough example on the latter argument, showing what I'm after.
addoption("-v", print("version 1.0"))
```

**EDIT: Example of what I want: (not working as is) (please ignore the ;'s)**

```
args = {};

def add(argument, command):
    args[argument] = lambda: command;  # Same problem when removing 'lambda:'

def run():
    for arg in args:
        arg();  # Causing problems.

def prnt():
    print("test");

add("-v", prnt);
run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: to correct your most recent code, iterating over a dictionary yields its keys not its values, so you need:

```
args = {};

def add(argument, command):
    args[argument] = command;

def run():
    for arg in args:
        args[arg]()     # <<<<<<<<<<

def prnt():
    print("test");

add("-v", prnt);
run();
```

For the example you give, a dictionary of functions, although possible, isn't really the natural way to go about things in Python. The standard library has a module, [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) specifically for dealing with all things commmand-line argument related, and rather than using keys to a dictionary you can parse the command line arguments and refer to their stored constants.

```
import argparse

def output_version():
    print('Version 1.0!')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="A program to do something.")
parser.add_argument('-v', help='Output version number.', action='store_true')

args = parser.parse_args()
if args.v:
    output_version()
```

(In fact outputting a version string is also handled natively by `argparse`: see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action)).

To print out the contents of a text file, `myfile.txt` when the `-p` switch is given:

```
import argparse

def print_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as fi:
        print(fi.read())

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="A program to do something.")
parser.add_argument('-p', help='Print a plain file.', action='store')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.p:
    print_file(args.p)
```

Use with e.g.

```
$ prog.py -p the_filename.txt
```

Comment: How would I print the contents of a plain file as an action for an argument?

Comment: You can define a function to do that and then call it when the argument parser contains the corresponding switch. Do you want to specify the filename on the command line too?

Comment: Definitely. I'm creating a generic module, in which I can **specify any** actions for **any and all** arguments **and files**.

Comment: You can certainly specify which filename to pass to the print function (see my edit)... but perhaps I don't understand: do you want to pass code to be executed on the command line?

Comment: Well, like in my Java example, that lambda function is generic. I can make it jump up and down, do a cartwheel, just by typing it. <- Is my goal. Yours has great command-line support which I've just tested now, except you are manually specifying what `args.p` does.

Comment: I want to include what `args.p` does as an argument to a function inside the module i'm creating, thus eliminating any other work other than `addargument("-p", print_file(args.p))`

Comment: In your edit you need to pass the actual function objects you want to call, so you can write `args[argument] = command` rather than `args[argument] = lambda: command`.

Comment: Yes, but even when doing that, the same error occurs. `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: Ah, I see: you're trying to call the keys to your dictionary instead of the values (which are the functions). See the top of my post.

Comment: OH MY GOD I LOVE YOU (**'nuff said**)

Comment: Now all I need to do is manually incorporate `argparse` into the mix.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can simply use the reference to a function as a value in a data structure. E.g., consider the following code:

```
def spam():
    print('Ham!')

eggs = [spam, spam, spam]
for x in eggs:
    x()
```

This would call three instances of the function `spam`.

The [lambda expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) you are referring to are simply another way to define functions, without explicitly having to bind them to a name. Consider the following:

```
eggs = [lambda : print('ham'), lambda : print('spam')]
for x in eggs:
    x()
```

This gets much more powerful when you're using arguments, though:

```
fn = [lambda x: return x + 3, lambda x: return x * 2]
for f in fn:
    print(f(4))
```

Once you have a reference to a function, you can then pass *that* to another function.

```
def foo(x):
    return x + 2

bar = lambda x: return x * 2

def h(g, f, x):
    return g(f(x))

print(h(foo, bar, 37))
```

In your scenario, however, you could simply pass `lambda : print("version 1.0")`.

Comment: That first example! Is there a way I can give `spam()` as an argument to a `def`?

Comment: Something like, `def foo(boo): boo()`

Comment: Sure (assuming I understood correctly). I'll update my answer. EDIT: Yes, precisely that.

Comment: Uhhh.. I'm sorta lost in the edit? How does that work?

Comment: It shows definitions for the functions `foo` and `bar` (both using `def` and using `lambda`), and then passes these functions to another function, `h`. The function `h` then calls them sequentially (i.e. passes the result from `f` to `g`). The result is printed. When calling `h`, we fill in the function `foo` for `f` and `bar` for `g`, but you can now use `h` to combine any two functions (assuming that the former outputs something the latter can deal with as input).

Comment: For some reason flake-8 is giving me all these errors when trying to create `bar`. **E731** and **E901**...

Comment: Rightfully so; I only wrote it out like that to show the versatility of function definitions, but using a lambda like that has no advantages over `def`, which is why PEP8 disapproves. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010167/e731-do-not-assign-a-lambda-expression-use-a-def).

Answer (score 0):

Since in Python functions are first-class objects, you may create dictionary of `{string: callable}` pairs.

```
def help():
    print("Usage: xyz")


d = {
    'help': help,
    'version': lambda: print("1.0"), # lambda is also callable
}
```

After definition like that usage would be following:

```
my_function = d["help"]  # retrieves function stored under key 'help' in dict
my_function()  # calls function

# or obviously you may drop explainatory variable
d['help']()
```

It'll work for your custom solution with problem defined like that.

For standardized way of creating command line interfaces you may want to get familiar with [argparse module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

Comment: Could I modify this to something like: `addargument(arg, function)`, host the function in a different module and call it with `addargument("-v", argnamegoeshere)`?

Answer (score -1):

Python has a function called [`eval()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383740/what-does-pythons-eval-do) that takes strings and tries to evaluate them as code.

```
>>> eval("2+3")
5
```

Then you can store your code as multi-line strings using 3 quotation marks

```
x = """the quick brown fox
jumps over the
lazy dogs"""
```

If you want to store the functions themselves, no reason why they can't also be placed in a dictionary.  Even without lambdas.

```
def f():
    return 1

def g(x):
    return x + 1

def h(x):
    return 2*x

F = [f,g,h]
G = {"a": f, "b": g, "c": h}

(F[0](), G["a"]())
```

The value of the tuple is `(1,1)`.  Otherwise I don't know what you are asking for.

Comment: @frayment Python doesn't really do that.  You can store *functions* or you can store the *code* as strings and evaluate them.

Comment: Well the former is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @frayment my example now includes a *list* of functions and a *dictionary* of functions.  does that work?

Comment: That last example is **partially** what I'm looking for. The problem is, is that you have hard-coded those values into place. I want to be able to call a function, which specifies my method to be run **as an argument**, and then dynamically store that argument in the dictionary.

Comment: @frayment maybe these methods are will be helpful to you.  good luck!