# Can i use a lambda expression here?

Tags: python, lambda

In this sample program I'm naming the days 0 through 6 where day 0 is Sunday and day 6 is Saturday. I'm wondering if I can use a lambda expression here for starting day and length of stay and still return the number of the day of the week I would return on. I'm having trouble understanding how to use lambda expressions in a simple example like this.

```
starting_day = 3
length_of_stay = 10
end_day = (starting_day + length_of_stay) % 7
print("You will come back on day: ", end_day)
```

Comment: A lambda expression is used to define anonymous **functions**. Where in this piece of code do you define a function you want to "anonymize" so to speak?

Comment: This seems backwards. You have a solution (lambda) and now you're trying to find a problem where you can use it?

Comment: @melpomene For learning purposes, that definitely seems apt. One must first to learn the uses of a tool before actually using it.

Comment: I don't understand, you already have a solution...

Comment: The challenge with this question is that there is no good reason to define a lambda here. lamdbas are functions and they need to be called to be useful. They are typically used when you want to pass a function to some other function that wants to use a callback. You could use an expression for your print, `print("You will come back on day: ", (starting_day + length_of_stay) % 7)`, but it would be silly to use a lambda `print("You will come back on day: ", (lambda start, length: (start + length) % 7)(starting_day, length_of_stay))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before thinking about how you'd write a *lambda* function for this, consider how you'd write a normal function.  It would probably look something like this:

```
def day_of_return(starting_day, length_of_stay):
    return (starting_day + length_of_stay) % 7
```

Then you can easily convert this to a lambda function:

```
day_of_return = lambda starting_day, length_of_stay: (starting_day + length_of_stay) % 7
```

or, with shorter variable names:

```
day_of_return = lambda s,l: (s+l) % 7
```

And then you could call it like this:

```
print(day_of_return(3,10))
```

**Edit**: In the comments, @daragua points out that assigning lambdas to a variable kind of defeats the purpose of a lambda, so you can also remove the assignment altogether:

```
print((lambda s,l: (s+l) % 7) (3,10)) # This will print 6
```

Comment: Well, assigning lambdas to variables [is considered an anti-pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25010243/) for debugging reasons essentially, and that it defeats the concept of `anonymous` functions :)

Comment: @ChristopherHumbert My pleasure! If an answer here solves your problem, please mark it as accepted if you don't mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Lambdas are functions, not expressions. They can be used anywhere a function is used. They are typically anonymous and very short.

Comment: Though lambdas are defined using [lambda expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#lambda).