# How to create a list from another list according to a function

Tags: python, list

I would like to create a list which has values which correspond to another list.
For example if I had:

```
listA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,...]
```

and I would like to create another list which is the same, except all the values were varied according to x^2 (or any other function), giving:

```
listB = [1, 4, 9, 16,25, ...]
```

I have already tried to do this by doing a while loop:

```
listA = [1, 2, 3, 4]
listB = range(1, 4, 1)
i = 0
while i <= 4:
    listB [i] = (listA [i]) ** 2
    i = i + 1
print listA
print listB
```

But it just spits out an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tim/Desktop/Python/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    listB [i] = (listA [i]) ** 2
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: Since nobody really addresses whats wrong: `i` starts at 0 and goes all the way up to and including `4`. `listA[0]` is 1, but there's no `listA[4]`, at most, theres `listA[3]`, which is 4.

Comment: And `range(1, 4, 1) ` is only 3 items. So `listA` is 4 items, `listB` is 3 items and the `while` loop is 5 items.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, all of these seem to have the same general idea, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this, using a lambda function to apply whatever change you want to each element in the list. In this case, the function is squaring every value in the list:

```
listA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,...]

operation = lambda x:x**2

new_list = map(operation, listA)
```

Also, you can perform the function operation in list comprehension:

```
new_list = [i**2 for i in listA]
```

Comment: I think the first solution will give you PEP8 - E731 warning:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010167/e731-do-not-assign-a-lambda-expression-use-a-def

Answer (score 5):

There is a smart syntax for building lists out of others:

```
listB = [x*x for x in listA]
```

Edit: Never use `range` as a list directly, even if it makes a list in Python 2, because it spits out a `range` object in Python 3. Use `list(range(...))` instead!

The popular **numpy** library provides a more concise syntax for doing such list operations, when the list would only consist out of numbers. It uses arrays that are faster in some circumstances like the element wise multiplication. The statement above can be rewritten as:

```
arrayB = arrayA * arrayA
```

or

```
arrayB = arrayA ** 2
```

or (not always recommended)

```
f = lambda a: a**2
arrayB = f(arrayA)
```

The element wise multiplication is sometimes referred to as the hadamard product, that comes from vector arithmetics (there is also `a@b` in numpy). In numpy you have to create the arrays with `np.array` or `np.arange`. The last is similar to `range` in Python 2 in the way, that it creates an array directly.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing what you are asking, others have pointed out `list` comprehensions and `map`s.

Reviewing your code:

```
listB = range(1, 4, 1)
```

The is only 3 items, `[1, 2, 3]`, `range()` is up to but not including the `stop` arg. You don't need to initialise your `listB` because you can just `listB.append()` in the loop, so `listB = []` is sufficient. Note in python3 this assigns a `range()` object to `listB` and it doesn't initialise the list as you intended.

```
i = 0
while i <= 4:
```

This loops 5 times, `i = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4`, and because this is more than `listB` (and `listA)` it results in the `IndexError` you are seeing. The normal way to do fixed loops would be with a `for` loop, e.g. `for i in range(4):`. However, you can loop directly over the elements in `listA` with `for i in listA:` and this would be considerd more pythonic

```
    listB [i] = (listA [i]) ** 2
```

This doesn't work because your loop goes to from `0` to `4` (inclusive) and `range(1, 4, 1)` is only 3 items `[1, 2, 3]`.

```
    i = i + 1
```

Unnecessary with a for `loop`.

Putting it all together and doing it iteratively as you've described you would do:

```
listA = [1, 2, 3, 4]
listB = []
for i in listA:
    listB.append(i**2)

print(listA)  # [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(listB)  # [1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Note: My preference would be for the list comprehension:

```
listB = [i**2 for i in listA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `numpy` library with a function called [power](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.power.html)

```
import numpy as np

listA = [1,2,3,4]

new_li = np.power(listA, 2)

print new_li

>>> [ 1  4  9 16]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python provides the `enumerate` function when you need to iterate over a list and need the index. That way you avoid easy-to-avoid `IndexError`s like these:

```
listA = [1, 2, 3, 4]
listB = [None]*4
for idx, item in enumerate(listA):
    listB[idx] = item ** 2
```

But in most cases you don't even need to create `listB` beforehand, you could let Python create it for you with `map` or a "list comprehension". The other answers already covered that but I wanted to share some way of using `map` without `lambda`:

```
import itertools
listB = list(map(pow, listA, itertools.repeat(2, len(listA))))
```

You can omit the outer `list()` if you're using python 2.x.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
listA = [1, 2, 3, 4]

listB = [x**2 for x in listA]
```

Or a normal loop:

```
listA = [1, 2, 3, 4]

listB = []
for x in listA:
    listB.append(x**2)
```

Comment: This doesn't add anything new, to the existing answers.

Comment: @AChampion, What do you mean? I think that my answer is more simple and easy to understand that others anwers.