# Auto-PEP8 is adding lines by turning my lambda into def function, how do I disable this specific auto format?

Tags: python, pep8, autopep8

I am using Visual Studio Code and PEP8 is automatically formatting a part of my code, I was just learning about lambdas and I had a 3 line code like this:

It went from this **3 line** code:

```
# Lambda example
divide = lambda x, y: x/y
print(divide(10, 2))
```

To this **7 line** code:

```
# Lambda example


def divide(x, y): return x/y


print(divide(10, 2))
```

Does anyone know how do I make this program to specifically not convert my lambda function into def function?

It has been formatting my code really good, so I don't want to completely disable this automatic feature, just for the lambda thing.

Comment: PEP8 is just doing it's job. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/25010243/3508192

Comment: The general rule of thumb is that when you're naming a lambda function, you should probably use a named one instead.

Comment: To be clear, you defining a lambda as a variable defeats the purpose of a lambda and so pep8 is just making what you did clearer. It's error `E731`, so that'd probably be what you'd want to get rid of if you want it not to transform your code.

Comment: @charliebeckwith Thank you, do you mind explaining or linking a source that explains why "defining a lambda as a variable" is wrong? 

Just so I have a better understanding of it, because upon googling "Python Lambda" examples come up assigning lambda to a variable, so I'm confused

Comment: I did, I think. And it's not "wrong". It's just, what you did is equivalent to defining a function except you're using lambdas in a way that are counterintuitive to their purpose. I don't wanna say antipattern, someone else will have to chime in... Here's another reference https://dzone.com/articles/pros-and-cons-lambda on why not to do that though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is triggered by the `pycodestyle` code `E731`

You can disable this with `--ignore=E731`

In a config file (for instance tox.ini / setup.cfg):

```
[pep8] 
ignore=E731
```

Comment: Just to be clear why - "E731 do not assign a lambda expression."

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This worked for me!  Just to be absolutely clear, to add this in VSCode, search for `python formatting args` in your Settings, then add in `--ignore=E731` as an additional input argument - https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlEqM.png

Answer (score 5):

There are some methods to disable auto converting lambda to function definition.

- Using `--ignore=E731` as explained by Anthony Sottile in (his/her) answer. Press `Ctrl+,`, search for `autopep8`, and add item `--ignore=E731` as shown in the following screenshot.

  [image]
- Or you uninstall `autopep8` first by invoking `pip uninstall autopep8` and then install `yapf` via `pip install yapf`.
- I let others add other methods from this line.

Comment: Replacing autopep8 with yapf worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is to put **parentheses** around the lambda assignment:

```py
divide = (lambda x, y: x/y)
```

autopep8 will not replace the above snippet with a `def`.

In general I would advise against this, as it goes against the PEP8 recommendations.

Nevertheless there are use cases for this, e.g. if the variable is
conditionally assigned to different functions,
which can look quite confusing when expressed using `def` s.