# Cannot get 1st and 2nd element of a list

Tags: python, list, function, sequence

I'm trying to write a function definition that takes a sequence and returns the first and second values. I suspect my code is wrong because it can't take in a list, but I'm not sure. Here's my goal:

> Write a function definition named first_and_second that takes in
>   sequence and returns the first and second value of that sequence as a
>   list.

Here's the code I'm having trouble with:

```py
def first_and_second(list):
  return list[0 and 1]
```

Here's the test of whether I got it right:

```
assert first_and_second([1, 2, 3, 4]) == [1, 2]
assert first_and_second(["python", "is", "awesome"]) == ["python", "is"]
```

Comment: @user1558604 this will return only the first item in the list.

Comment: @DarkLeader, oh, yeah...

Comment: python is pretty literal in its syntax, but not that much.... `and` is a boolean operator, slicing is done by `:` - `list[0:2]` (the `2` is because the end part is exclusive)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with how your function "*takes in a list*", but there's something wrong with how you use the passed list.

```
return list[0 and 1]
```

The expression `0 and 1` evaluates to `0`:

```
>>> 0 and 1
0
```

So that code effectively becomes:

```
return list[0]
```

which will only return the 1st element. What you want to do is called [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/2745495), which means getting a subset of a list. From this SO post on [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/2745495):

> ```
> a[start:stop]  # items start through stop-1
> a[start:]      # items start through the rest of the array
> a[:stop]       # items from the beginning through stop-1
> a[:]           # a copy of the whole array
> ```

The correct code is:

```
def first_and_second(aList):
  return aList[0:2]
```

which means "*get the elements of `aList` from the index=0 element (the first value) up to the index=1 element (the second value)*".

```
>>> def first_and_second(list):
...   return list[0:2]
>>> print( first_and_second([1, 2, 3, 4]) == [1, 2] )
True
>>> print( first_and_second(["python", "is", "awesome"]) == ["python", "is"] )
True
```

Also, note that I changed the function parameter `list` to `aList`. **DO NOT name your parameters/variables as `list`** because that is a [built-in type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) in Python.

Comment: @BenTaylor Great that my answer helped you :) I see that you are a new contributor. Here at Stack Overflow, if an answer helped you, consider marking it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

```
def first_and_second(list):
    return [list[0],list[1]]
```

or

```
def first_and_second(list):
    return list[0:2]
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more concise solution, you can use lambda notation:

```
first_and_second = lambda l : l[:2]
```

It requires only one keyword instead of two and may therefore be considered a more pythonic way of doing simple things like this.

Since the lambda statement above actually is a function defition, you can just use it as follows:

```
assert first_and_second([1, 2, 3, 4]) == [1, 2]
assert first_and_second(["python", "is", "awesome"]) == ["python", "is"]
```

Comment: While it works, PEP8 could complain that [you shouldn't assign a lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25010167/2745495).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This seems to be one of the more debatable PEP8 rules, however, as one can see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010167/e731-do-not-assign-a-lambda-expression-use-a-def