# Method vs function-valued field in Python

Tags: python, methods

I am switching from MATLAB to Python and numpy and I would like to know if there is any difference between the option to define a class method and the option to the function to a  class field (instance variable)? Here is the example:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a):            
        self.a=a    #some variable

    def add(self,b):
        return self.a+b
```

vs

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a=a    #some variable            
        self.add = lambda b: self.a+b
```

It works in both cases when I call

```
my_object=MyClass(2)
print(my_object.add(2)) #prints 4
```

Are there any differences between these two approaches? Any best practices/downsides?
To me, the first one feels more "proper OOP", but the second one feels more flexible. Or, maybe, the definitions are identical, because of the way Python works under the hood?

Comment: The first one is a method, the second one  is just a function that is an attribute. Note, for a method, a single function object on the class, whereas if you assign a function to an attribute, a separate function object exists for every instance.

Comment: Best practice is not to use a `lambda` function and assign it to a variable, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010167/e731-do-not-assign-a-lambda-expression-use-a-def.

Answer (score 2):

The second one can't be overridden and takes a lot more space, because there's a separate function in every instance's `__dict__` instead of one function in the class `__dict__`. (Instance method objects are created and reclaimed on the fly if you do it the normal way, or optimized out entirely in many cases depending on Python version.)