# I want to change this def by using lambda

Tags: python

```
import random

def Calculate_Pi(total):
    inside = 0
    for i in range(0, total):
        x2 = random.random() ** 2
        y2 = random.random() ** 2
        if x2 + y2 <= 1.0:
            inside += 1
    pi = (float(inside) / total) * 4
    return pi
```

I want to change this def by using lambda

```
import random as r

total = int(input("total : "))
pi = lambda inside : float(len([x for x in range(total) if r.random()**2 + r.random()**2 <= 1.0]) / total) * 4
print(pi(total))
```

this is my code but i don't know this is right and i want to know any better code

Comment: `pi = lambda` no, don't assign a lambda to a name.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010167/e731-do-not-assign-a-lambda-expression-use-a-def

Comment: But in any case, your `lambda` is incorrect, you need `total` to be the argument, not inside. I would have used the expression `(sum(1 for _ in range(total) if (random.random() ** 2) + (random.random() ** 2) <= 1.0) / total) * 4`

Comment: Why would you do this to yourself? whats wrong with the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want this but you can do it this way

```
calculate_pi = lambda total:(sum(((random.random()**2) + (random.random()**2)) <=1.0 for _ in range(total)) / total) * 4

print(calculate_pi(5)) # 3.2
```

Comment: ~~~((random.random()**2) + (random.random()**2)) <=1.0~~~      Only when here is true            ~~~for _ in range(total)~~~     here is work?

Comment: `((random.random()**2) + (random.random()**2)) <=1.0` this results to `True` or `False`, in python you can add `True` and `False`, `True` = `1` and `False` = `0` @윤희제