# How to parse values from a specific key of multiple JSON objects python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to parse the key "tags" from the below JSON.

```
data = [{
    "12233":{
    "title": "The Title",
    "id": "12233",
    "tags": ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"],
    },
    "122223":{
    "title": "The Title",
    "id": "122223",
    "tags": ["tag4", "tag5", "tag6"],
    },
    "122344":{
    "title": "The Title",
    "id": "122344",
    "tags": ["tag7", "tag8", "tag9"],
    }
}]
```

I have tried this so far,

```
data = data[0]
tags_list = []

for tags in data:
    tags_list.append(tags["122344"])

print(tags_list)
```

But it only extracts the first object, I want the result to be like this,

```
tags_list = ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3", "tag4", "tag5", "tag6","tag7", "tag8", "tag9"]
```

Comment: try using list compression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is this will solve your problem?

```
tags_list = [item for k in data for t in k for item in k[t]['tags']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use itemgetter on all values of dictionary data[0] and sum all items to empty list []

```py
from operator import itemgetter

data = [{
    "12233":{
    "title": "The Title",
    "id": "12233",
    "tags": ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"],
    },
    "122223":{
    "title": "The Title",
    "id": "122223",
    "tags": ["tag4", "tag5", "tag6"],
    },
    "122344":{
    "title": "The Title",
    "id": "122344",
    "tags": ["tag7", "tag8", "tag9"],
    }
}]

tag_getter = itemgetter('tags')
# map to get list of all tags
# Adding all the list of tags to []
sum(map(tag_getter, data[0].values()), [])
```

```
['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4', 'tag5', 'tag6', 'tag7', 'tag8', 'tag9']
```

If you want to merge all tags from all the entries of list then use

```py
from operator import itemgetter
tag_getter = itemgetter('tags')
def all_tags(d):
    return sum(map(tag_getter, d.values()), [])
sum(map(all_tags, data), [])
```

Comment: Lambdas in Python are designed to be anonymous functions. There is no sense in assign one to a variable, making it a named function. It is considered bad practice. If you need that, define a function instead. See (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25010243/6789321) and (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations).

Answer (score 0):

In stead of a single loop, you need two loops to iterate over the inner dictionaries. Try this :

```
tags_list = []
for k in data:
    for t in k:
        tags_list.extend(k[t]['tags'])
```

Output `tags_list` :

```
['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4', 'tag5', 'tag6', 'tag7', 'tag8', 'tag9']
```