# python lambda : maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Tags: python, lambda-calculus

I wrote the following code in Python:

```
func = lambda x : x * 2
func = lambda x : func(x)
func(6)
```

When I ran the code above, I got

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

I think the reason maybe : when it runs, it looks like this :

```
func = lambda x : lambda x: lambda x: (bula bula ...)
```

But why shouldn't it be like this :

```
func = lambda x : lambda x : x * 2
```

Or any other reasons?

Comment: As an aside, `lambda` is used to define anonymous functions within other expressions. When you do `func = lambda x: x * 2`, you immmediately assign an anonymous function to a variable. That's what `def` does. If you want your function in a named variable, just use `def`. There are many `lambda` examples that do what you did, I know. But those are horrible examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `func = lambda x : func(x)`, you are redefining `func` to be that lambda, which just calls itself repeatedly until it bottoms out at the recursion limit. Consider a `def` version of the same:

```py
def i_call_myself_forever(x):
    return i_call_myself_forever(x)
```

Your lambda is doing the same thing.

I think what you are trying to do is call the first definition of `func` from the second. That being the case, just give them distinct names and you'll be fine.

Additionally, you're not correctly understanding what `func = lambda x : lambda x : x * 2` means. What's happening is that the top level `lambda` is returning another `lambda`, namely `lambda x : x * 2`. That second level lambda uses the same parameter name `x` and as such [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the `x` from the top level `lambda`. You could call it as follows

```py
func = lambda x : lambda x : x * 2
intermediate_func = func(5) # 5 is captured but never used
assert intermediate_func(6) == 12 # this is calling lambda x : x * 2
```

Let's also try a `def` version to be as clear as possible:

```py
def i_return_a_function(x):
   def im_an_inner_function(x):
       # my x shadows i_return_a_function's x
       return x * 2
   return im_an_inner_function # notice how i_return_a_function's x is never used
```

Finally, I want to emphasize @tdelaney's comment: Sure, there are plenty of examples of people assigning `lambda`s to a name out there in the wild, but that doesn't mean that doing so is considered good practice. There's [some disagreement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25010167/12162258) in the community about how strict to be about this, but my rule of thumb is to only use `lambda` when the function is a single expression (which is all you can express with a python `lambda`) that I'm using exactly once.