# How to use lambda in iterating list with if statement?

Tags: python, lambda

I have this working for loop,
I want to use lambda that prints same results below

```
ids= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
val = [20,30,26,38,40,22,35]
list1=[]
for i,num  in enumerate(val):
  if num > 29:
  list1.append(ids[i])
print("ids",list1)

#output ids [2, 4, 5, 7]
```

The code below throws and invalid syntax.
I just want to get the element value not the index.

```
new_id=list(filter(lambda ids[i]:   
val[i]>29, range(len(val))))
```

Comment: like this but it returns bolean, list(map(lambda x: x >29, val))

Comment: `list(filter(lambda x: x>29, val))`

Answer (score 2):

You can create `lambda` function to compare the value and return boolean, and call this function in your if condition. It's not a recommended way though [E731 do not assign a lambda expression, use a def](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010167/e731-do-not-assign-a-lambda-expression-use-a-def):

```py
list1=[]
get_flag = lambda i:i>29
for i in val:
    if get_flag(i):
        list1.append(i)
print(list1)
[30, 38, 40, 35]
```

Or, you can just use `filter` builtin and pass a lambda function. It's equivalent List Comprehension is already there in another answer.

```py
list(filter(lambda i: i>29, val))
[30, 38, 40, 35]
```

For updated question, to get the index, just iterate a range and filter out based on the values at given index:

```py
>>> list(filter(lambda i: val[i]>29, range(len(val))))
[1, 3, 4, 6]
```

Comment: i have edited my code, as it cant give me the index  ids to append .

Comment: @Glenn_ford7 That apparently becomes a new question, but no worries, I can update the answer

Comment: it does return, but the only the elements with < 29

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use lambda function,
Then it will be,

```
val = [20,30,26,38,40,22,35]
fun = lambda val: [v for v in val if v>29]
res = fun(val)
# [30, 38, 40, 35]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why lambdas, but I think you might be referring to something like this:

```
filtered = [x for x in val if x > 29]
```

This seems to be the most code-efficient way to achieve what you're asking.