# Assign a default callable value for a callable protocol

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have the following callable `Protocol`:

```py
class OnStarted(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, kwargs: Dict[str, Any]) -> Optional[Dict[str, Any]]: ...
```

that I want to assign a default function, which I did like this:

```py
def foo(on_started: OnStarted = lambda _: {}):
    pass
```

but MyPy isn't happy with it and complains with this error:

```
foo.py:172: error: Incompatible default for argument "on_started" (default has type "Callable[[Any], Dict[<nothing>, <nothing>]]", argument has type "OnStarted")  [assignment]
foo.py:172: note: "OnStarted.__call__" has type "Callable[[Arg(Dict[str, Any], 'kwargs')], Optional[Dict[str, Any]]]"
```

How can I fix that so that `on_started` has a default value and MyPy doesn't error?

Comment: It can't infer that `{}` is potentially `Dict[str, Any]`, `lambda _: None` would work, or maybe `lambda _: cast(Dict[str, Any], {})`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh I see. This means mypy doesn't know it's an empty dict that actually would satisfy the requirement (which was my assumption), but it recognizes an untyped dict thus failing the typing hints.

Comment: You can see what it's inferred - `Dict[<nothing>, <nothing>]`, which is apparently not compatible with `Dict[str, Any]`. `{"": 0}` is about the shortest value that would get inferred correctly, but probably isn't what you want to be returning!

Comment: @jonrsharpe now that you're saying this LOL, face-palm heh. I'll give you the tick if you want to post it as an answer ;-]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of the error is the return type, which is required to be `Optional[Dict[str, Any]]` but being inferred for the lambda expression as `Dict[<nothing>, <nothing>]`, a *permanently* empty dictionary.

(`<nothing>` [isn't documented](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3030), but it's a "bottom type", you get the same behaviour using [`Never`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Never).)

This is hard to predict, because any simpler example is just fine:

```py
d: Dict[str, Any] = {}  # fine

c: Callable[[Dict[str, Any]], Dict[str, Any]] = lambda _: {}  # fine


def f(on_started: Callable[[Dict[str, Any]], Dict[str, Any]] = lambda _: {}):  # fine
    pass

def foo(on_started: OnStarted = lambda _: {}):  # no thanks
    pass
```

If you want to keep it inline, you have to give the type system a little more information, e.g.:

```
def foo(on_started: OnStarted = lambda _: cast(Dict[str, Any], {})):
    pass
```

Unfortunately this also breaks type safety, as `cast(Dict[str, Any], "lol")` is accepted too.

Given that the response type is optional, `lambda _: None` would be a valid and inferrable default.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) *:

> Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier.

Namely, you will gain clarity if you write a regular function to set it as a default value. Plus, you can add documentation to explain why you need a default function, what the default does, it's easier to change.

For this you can follow the PEP8 recommendation and simply define your default function as a regular one.

```py
def default_on_started(kwargs: Dict[str, Any]) -> Optional[Dict[str, Any]]: 
    return {}

def foo(on_started: OnStarted = default_on_started):
    print(on_started({}))
```

*: We might argue that this line is only for regular body code (@jonrshape) in comment in this post gave good points. If you are interested, there is a discussion in the comments.

Comment: There's no point putting an implementation in `OnStarted`, because `TypeError: Protocols cannot be instantiated`.

Comment: I can use a `def` as a default!? That's just cool! Also with the `return` in the same line.

Comment: You are right, we cannot instanciate Protocol, big mistake. Thanks.

Comment: (Also I don't think that's the intent of _"an assignment statement that binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier"_, e.g. PyCharm's Pylint doesn't warn using a `lambda` as a default value but does for top-level assignments. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25010243/3001761. And if you're following PEP8 _"Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are generally discouraged"_!)

Comment: @t3chb0t you can use _any_ value as a default, [`def`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) is just a statement for defining a function value.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I do think this PEP8 line can hold in this case. Assigning a default value to a parameter is a "binding" to an identifier. But I get what you are saying and I am not 100% of my opinion. Actually So I will add this post to my answer, thanks again.

Comment: @MathiasRéus I see what you're saying, but flake8's E731 doesn't consider it a violation and a Pylint maintainer says it's [completely fine](https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint/issues/5976#issuecomment-1079076107). It's a very common usage pattern!

Comment: Yes, I totally agree. I should have put my return line after a new line.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Wait, use a lambda expression for **an argument** is totally ok. In this case, we use it as **a parameter** which is different. So it's not the same use case at all. I do think it's thin ice here about using a lambda in the parameter case. From what I understand, when something is statically defined such as a variable in code body, we do not use lambda. Although, when you use a function such as `sort` with its argument `key`, it's ok to use a lambda function because if you have to repeat the usage of sort, you won't type 20 def. While the default value is typed only once.