# I want to delete a print with two lines in terminal using python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, printing

I was searching for a way to do that kind of thing :

```py
import time

print("Hi !\nHow are you ?")
time.sleep(1)
# Clear the printed text
print("New\nText")
```

So output should look like this :

```
Hi !
How are you ?

# Wait 1 sec

New
Text
```

So I tried using `\r` and `flush` on print like this :

```
from time import sleep
print("Test\nTEST", end='', flush=True)
sleep(1)
print("\r", end='')
```

But nothing worked :/

Comment: This depends on what terminal emulator you are using and what its support for escape sequences are. Python can't control how the terminal displays the text to you. All it can do is write new characters to the output stream

Answer (score 1):

```py
from time import sleep

def delete_line():
    print("\033[1A\x1b[2K", end="")

print("Hi !\nHow are you ?")
sleep(1)

delete_line()
delete_line()
print("New\nText")
```

This will produce your desired output. For more info, you can check out [this article](https://itnext.io/overwrite-previously-printed-lines-4218a9563527).

Comment: Hi !
Thanks for this quick response unfortunately, I'm using an emulated terminal so it doesn't work :/
If no solution exists, this solution will suit me but if there is something that exists and works on every terminal...

Comment: That's unfortunate. Yeah, the best solution is to use `"\r"` but that can only delete a single line.

Comment: @nate-thegrate Why not use `print("\033[2A", end="")`?

Comment: Okay thanks ! 
That's fine with me it was just to know^^

Comment: @nokla I tried out that print statement; it didn't delete the "Hi ! How are you ?", it just started overwriting: output was `"New! Textare you ?"`

Comment: Don't assign a name to a lambda, it defeats the purpose. Just define a function instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010167/e731-do-not-assign-a-lambda-expression-use-a-def

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to remove the last 2 lines:

```py
print("\033[2A", end="")
```

Or, you can do it line by line:

```py
print("\033[1A", end="")
```

Also, you can use this to clear the entire console:

```py
print("\033[H\033[J", end="")
```